# Poincaré inequality on metric spaces

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

In this [book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=UgDY3FYw9l8C&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=weak+poincare+inequality+bilipschitz&source=bl&ots=j942EzYAOH&sig=XUZZkP-HIr_Ip6I7cBfDp7xdQwo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UWMnU4W9BM62kAf4oICADA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=weak%20poincare%20inequality%20bilipschitz&f=false), page 91, example 4.18, it is said that the space $$Y=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\ |z|=1,\ \arg z\in [-T,T]\}$$

where $3<T<\pi$ does not support a strong Poincare inequality (see page 84 for the definition). Does anyone knows why this is true?

They said that $Y$ does admits a weak Poincare inequality with dilation constant $\lambda\to \infty$ if $T\to \pi$, however I fail to see this. Because $\Phi$ is an isometry, it seems to me that $Y$ also admits a strong Poincare inequality. Maybe I am doing some mitake here in my calculations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But $\Phi(x)=e^{ix}$ is not an isometry. The space $Y$ carries the restriction metric from $\mathbb C$. Because of this, a   ball $B$ centered at $e^{iT}\in Y$  looks like this (colored   red):

[image]

One can imagine a nice function $g:Y\to \mathbb R$ that has zero gradient on $B$ but takes different values on two components of $B$. This is why the strong form of the Poincaré inequality fails.

The weak form still holds, but  $\lambda B$ must be large enough to cover all of $Y$, because the gradient of $g$ could be supported on a short arc somewhere far on the right. This is why a very large $\lambda$ may be needed.

Comment: Man, I feel illuminated now hehe, thank you, I was doing everything wrong.

Comment: I want not abuse of your help, but am I right to say that if $\Phi$ is an isometry between metric spaces $X,Y$ then, if $X$ carries a Poincare inequality with constant $\lambda=1$ then $Y$ will do also?

Comment: @Tomás Yes, provided that $\Phi$ also pushes the measure along. The PI is  a property of a **metric measure space**, not just a metric space. So, any map that preserves both metric and measure will preserve the PI property.